# Is it possible to cast before passing to base constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create an abstract generic manager which would give events for added/removed and provide abstract method for creating and finalizing an item.

Below is the code I've come up with, however in TestClass constructor passing TestManager for a ManagerBase argument to base produces compiler error for invalid cast even though TestManager is certainly a ManagerBase.

It is possible to make the Manager field an "object" and cast in at run time, but that'd be pretty ugly.

Is it possible to make it work, or perhaps I'm in the wrong direction?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ManagerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Manager = new TestManager();
            Manager.ItemAdded += (manager, item) => Debug.WriteLine("Item added: " + item.Id);
            Manager.ItemRemoved += (manager, item) => Debug.WriteLine("Item removed: " + item.Id);

            var entity1 = Manager.Create("entity1");
            var entity2 = Manager.Create("entity2");
            Manager.Remove("entity1");
            var entity3 = Manager.Create("entity3");
            Manager.Remove("entity3");
            Manager.Remove("entity4");
        }
    }

    class TestClass : EntityBase, IDisposable
    {
        public TestClass(string id, TestManager manager) : base(id, manager) { Debug.WriteLine(Id + " - ctor"); }
        public void Dispose() { Debug.WriteLine(Id + " - disposed"); }
    }

    class TestManager : ManagerBase<TestClass>
    {
        protected override TestClass CreateInternal(string key) { return new TestClass(key, this); }
        protected override void FinalizeRemove(TestClass item) { item.Dispose(); }
    }

    abstract class EntityBase
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public ManagerBase<EntityBase> Manager { get; private set; }

        public EntityBase(string id, ManagerBase<EntityBase> manager)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Manager = manager;
        }
    }

    abstract class ManagerBase<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        public event Action<ManagerBase<T>, T> ItemAdded;
        public event Action<ManagerBase<T>, T> ItemRemoved;

        private readonly Dictionary<string, T> Storage = new Dictionary<string, T>();

        protected abstract T CreateInternal(string key);
        protected abstract void FinalizeRemove(T item);

        public T Create(string key)
        {
            T newItem = null;

            lock (Storage)
            {
                if (!Storage.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    newItem = CreateInternal(key);

                    Storage.Add(key, newItem);

                    ItemAdded.SafeInvoke(this, newItem);
                }
            }

            return newItem;
        }

        public T Get(string key)
        {
            lock (Storage)
                return Storage.ContainsKey(key) ? Storage[key] : null;
        }

        public bool Contains(string key)
        {
            lock (Storage)
                return Storage.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public bool Remove(string key)
        {
            bool returnValue = false;

            lock (Storage)
                if (Storage.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    var item = Storage[key];
                    returnValue = Storage.Remove(key);
                    ItemRemoved.SafeInvoke(this, item);
                    FinalizeRemove(item);
                }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void SafeInvoke<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
        {
            var actionCopy = action;
            if (actionCopy != null)
                actionCopy(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The arguments passed to `base(..)` are just expressions, so: `base(.., (ManagerBase<EntityBase>)manager)` (you can even invoke static methods in such expressions). Of course, it's messy and I'm not entirely sold it's valid .. YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corrected code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ManagerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Manager = new TestManager();
            Manager.ItemAdded += (manager, item) => Debug.WriteLine("Item added: " + item.Id);
            Manager.ItemRemoved += (manager, item) => Debug.WriteLine("Item removed: " + item.Id);

            var entity1 = Manager.Create("entity1");
            var entity2 = Manager.Create("entity2");
            Manager.Remove("entity1");
            var entity3 = Manager.Create("entity3");
            Manager.Remove("entity3");
            Manager.Remove("entity4");
        }
    }

    class TestClass : EntityBase, IDisposable
    {
        public TestClass(string id, TestManager manager) : base(id, manager) { Debug.WriteLine(Id + " - ctor"); }
        public void Dispose() { Debug.WriteLine(Id + " - disposed"); }
    }

    class TestManager : ManagerBase<TestClass>, IManagerBase<TestClass>
    {
        protected override TestClass CreateInternal(string key) { return new TestClass(key, this); }
        protected override void FinalizeRemove(TestClass item) { item.Dispose(); }
    }

    abstract class EntityBase
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }
        public IManagerBase<EntityBase> Manager { get; private set; }

        public EntityBase(string id, IManagerBase<EntityBase> manager)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Manager = manager;
        }
    }

    interface IManagerBase<out T>
        where T : EntityBase
    {
        event Action<IManagerBase<T>, T> ItemAdded;
        event Action<IManagerBase<T>, T> ItemRemoved;
        T Create(string key);
        T Get(string key);
        bool Contains(string key);
        bool Remove(string key);
    }

    abstract class ManagerBase<T> : IManagerBase<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        public event Action<IManagerBase<T>, T> ItemAdded;
        public event Action<IManagerBase<T>, T> ItemRemoved;

        private readonly Dictionary<string, T> Storage = new Dictionary<string, T>();

        protected abstract T CreateInternal(string key);
        protected abstract void FinalizeRemove(T item);

        public T Create(string key)
        {
            T newItem = null;

            lock (Storage)
            {
                if (!Storage.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    Storage.Add(key, CreateInternal(key));

                    ItemAdded.SafeInvoke(this, newItem);
                }
            }

            return newItem;
        }

        public T Get(string key)
        {
            lock (Storage)
                return Storage.ContainsKey(key) ? Storage[key] : null;
        }

        public bool Contains(string key)
        {
            lock (Storage)
                return Storage.ContainsKey(key);
        }

        public bool Remove(string key)
        {
            bool returnValue = false;

            lock (Storage)
                if (Storage.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    var item = Storage[key];
                    returnValue = Storage.Remove(key);
                    ItemRemoved.SafeInvoke(this, item);
                    FinalizeRemove(item);
                }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static void SafeInvoke<T1, T2>(this Action<T1, T2> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
        {
            var actionCopy = action;
            if (actionCopy != null)
                actionCopy(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the invariance of the T parameter in ManagerBase. You can't assign `ManagerBase<Derived>` to `ManagerBase<Base>`. You would be able to do that if the parameter was covariant, but this can be done inly in interfaces, not in classes. So maybe try to make the managerbase an interface? Like `IManager<out T>`

This article explains covariance/contravariance stuff quite well: http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Comment: Yep, I meant out. Covariant.

Comment: Thanks for the article, both your and Maxim's answers are what I was looking for. Maxim's answer seems more precise, but yours seems more informative. I'd vote you up but I don't have the reputation to do that.